# JOGL Blank Screen

Tags: java

I have just bought the book called "Computer Graphics Programming in OpenGL with Java" by V.SCOTT GORDON AND JOHN CLEVENGER. For the sample code, the book shows you that;

```
package com.company;
import java.nio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;

public class Main extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {

    private GLCanvas canvas;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        setTitle("Chapter - program1");
        setSize(600,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(200,200);

        canvas = new GLCanvas();
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);

        this.add(canvas);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {

    }

    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {

    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {

        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        float[] bkg = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
        FloatBuffer bkgBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(bkg);
        gl.glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR,0,bkgBuffer);

    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

    }
}
```

I wrote the exact same code and got a black screen, it's supposed to be red. Can someone help me with that, please?

I added the jogl-all.jar, gluegen-rt.jar packages as Global Library.

Comment: Add an animator

Answer (score 0):

Getting a blank screen is probably the most common error when using OpenGL.  Since this is apparently the first OpenGL/JOGL program you've attempted, by far the most likely reason is something wrong in your configuration.  Unfortunately, there are MANY possible causes.  I've listed a bunch of them here, any of which can cause the blank screen you see:
http://ecs.csus.edu/~gordonvs/hints.html
I'd suggest going through each of those first, to make sure your configuration is completely correct.  Getting that first program to work can be a bit of a hassle. :)

I notice that your program listing is actually very slightly different than the actual example listed in the book (you added a package declaration).  That probably isn't the source of the problem, but I thought I'd mention it.